# Modal viewcontroller subviews

Tags: ios, swift, viewcontroller

I am presenting a view controller modally (transparent) and then trying to add a dialogue box as a subview with a few buttons. I would like this subview to be solid colour however and not transparent, but can't get it to work.

I have tried setting the alpha of the subview to 1 but it's not changing the appearance.

```
class GameOverViewController: UIViewController {
    private let restart = UIButton(type: .custom)
    private let mainmenu = UIButton(type: .custom)

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        //displays view controller modally
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.view.backgroundColor = .white
        self.view.alpha = 0.6
        self.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext

        //add dialogue box
        let dialoguebox = UIView(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: self.view.frame.width / 2, y: self.view.frame.height / 2), size: CGSize(width: self.view.frame.width / 2, height: self.view.frame.height / 2)))
        dialoguebox.backgroundColor = .red
        dialoguebox.center = self.view.center
        dialoguebox.alpha = 1
        self.view.addSubview(dialoguebox)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
    self.view.alpha = 0.6
```

That affects the `alpha` of this view *and all its subviews*, including your dialog box. You cannot make the dialog have full effective opacity, because it inherits its transparency from `self.view`.

What you probably meant to do is give `self.view.backgroundColor` some transparency. So do not make it pure `.white`; make it `.white` along with some lower alpha value.

Comment: Makes sense, works, thanks! All seems so obvious afterwards... oO